# All possible combinations of letters from a list, from 1 to 20 - python

Tags: python, combinations, combinatorics, python-itertools

Currently trying to get this to create all possible combinations of these 20 letters in a list, (without repeats)

```
letters = ['G','A','L','M','F','W','K','Q','E','S','P','V','I','C','Y','H','R','N','D','T']

combinations = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.combinations(letters,r=20)]
```

Output I'm looking for is a list like:

```
combinations = ['G','A','L','M','F','W','K','Q','E','S','P','V','I','C','Y','H','R','N','D','T',GG,GA,GL,GM... ...GALMFWKQESPVICYHRNDT]
```

Comment: Is the order of the combination important? i.e: is the same GA than AG?

Comment: Nope, not at all!

Comment: @Neosage What's the desired output???

Comment: It's in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a nested loop in the list comprehension to iterate through all possible lengths:

```
letters = ['G','A','L','M','F','W','K','Q','E','S','P','V','I','C','Y','H','R','N','D','T']

combinations = [''.join(i) for j in range(1,len(letters) + 1) for i in itertools.combinations(letters,r=j)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
letters = ['G','A','L','M','F','W','K','Q','E','S','P','V','I','C','Y','H','R','N','D','T']

def gen_combinations(opts):
    for index in range(2 ** len(opts)):
        mask = bin(index)[2:].zfill(len(opts))
        selected = [o for (o,m) in zip(opts, mask) if m == '1']
        yield ''.join(selected)
```

If you want only some of the possibilities:

```
for (i,x) in enumerate(gen_combinations(letters)):
    print(x)
    if i > 10: break
```

Output:

```
       # The empty set
T
D
DT
N
NT
ND
NDT
R
RT
RD
RDT
```

If you want them all:

```
all_combinations = list(gen_combinations(letters))
print(len(all_combinations))    # 1048576
```

This uses a generator that looks at the binary representation of a (in this case) 20-bit number, and if the bit is 1, adds that item to the output list for that iteration.

There will be 2^len(opts) list elements -- in this case 2^20 -- all the possible combinations.

P.S. `bin(i)` is typically faster than doing bit manipulation, but I'm not sure that still holds with the added `zfill`.